# “De” vs “des” in plural context

Tags: grammaire, articles, pluriel, prépositions

I have a problem when I try to use *des*. For example, which of these sentences are correct:

1. *Je vois de lapins.*
2. *Je vois des lapins.*
3. *Difficultés de missions.*
4. *Difficultés des missions.*

I need to know when I have to use *de* in plural context and when I have to use *des*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is probably one of the worse...
It has a lot of exceptions and cases to handle.

For exemple you could say :

- *J'ai **des** lapins*.

But you can also say :

- *J'ai beaucoup **de** lapins*.

But, this also works :

- *Je n'ai pas **de** lapins*.

And this also :

- *J'ai **de** très gros lapins*.(1)

While this also works..

- *J'ai **des** très gros lapins*.(2)

Yes I just wrote a sentence where **both** *de* and *des* fit, but actually doesn't have the same exact meaning. (1) uses *de* to increase the impact of the adjective *très gros*, while (2) uses *des* just as a plain article. It would be actually quite hard to explain the exact reason why *de* or why *des* on a lot of cases (as a French Canadian) since often we use the one that just "Sounds better".

There are **a lot** of specific and different cases.

I would recommand you [this website](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/de-vs-du-de-la-des_3.htm) that I found searching on google that explains clearly when to use *de*, *des*, *du*, etc.

EDIT : I also wanted to add that, in many cases like these listed, *des* is used for a little groups, while *de* is used for big groups.

- *J'ai **des** lapins*. (some rabbits)
- *J'ai beaucoup **de** lapins*. (a lot of rabbits)

Comment: It should be worth noting that there are rules behind these *exception cases*. When using the adverb `beaucoup`, it must be followed by **de**, and **de** is *always singular*. This concept also applies to negations, as in your example. When you negate the verb `avoir` (*je n'ai pas*), it is generally followed by **de**, but is also *always singular*. You wouldn't say, for example, *je n'ai pas **des** livres*. You would also never say *j'ai beaucoup **des** livres* because in these two cases - negation and the adverb `beaucoup` - the **de** is singular, where it would normally be plural.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice
I would like to precise though that **de** is still **plural** ( not singular) in all of these cases. Which also happens to be OP's requested context.

Comment: Good point, I didn't fully read the OP's question, I just read your answer! You're correct :)

Comment: Un autre example de "L'Étranger": "Il est assez petit, avec de larges épaules et un nez de boxeur."

Comment: @ChrisCirefice *When using the adverb beaucoup, it must be followed by de*: Well, there are indeed rules behind the exceptions, but there are also exceptions behind the rules ;-) ***Beaucoup des** lapins que j'ai vus sont blancs*.

Answer (score 6):

These are correct...

- **J'ai des lapins** : standard usage
- **J'ai beaucoup de lapins** : *des* reduced to *de* is standard when used with collective nouns (beaucoup de, un groupe de, une quantité de, une grappe de, ...)
- **Je n'ai pas de lapins** : *des* reduced to *de* is standard when the verb is negative
- **J'ai de gros lapins** : *des* reduced to *de* is standard when the noun is preceded by an adjective

Answer (score 1):

Sentences 2 and 4 are right.

In this context, I think that 'de' is only used in a negation and when you talk about quantity.

> Je ne vois pas de lapins.

or

> Je vois beaucoup de lapins

but not with numbers!

> Je vois deux lapins

**Note**: A negation is not with 'de' when you use the verb 'être'. Then it's just

> Je ne suis pas **un** lapin.

Answer (score 1):

De is used instead of des if you are using an adjective placed before the noun.eg: "des oiseaux blancs" but "De grands oiseaux blancs"

Answer (score -6):

You have to use "**des**" when there are many objects (lapin**S** here)

and "**de**" when there is only one object (**1** lapin here)

Comment: Your answer is just the very general case, but there are plenty of exceptions. See accepted answer and comments,