# Pourquoi « j'ai besoin DE lunettes » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

Pourquoi dans cette question on utilise « de » et pas « des » avec le nom pluriel « lunettes » ? Si on parlait de n'importe quels autres objets au pluriel, on dirait « des », comme dans :

> J'ai besoin des clients.
>
> J'ai besoin des vacances.

Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres substantifs qui se comportent de la même façon ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elle a de/des longs cheveux](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/elle-a-de-des-longs-cheveux)

Comment: La différence est que le groupe nominal est dans l'un des cas indéfini et dans l'autre défini: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de, voir la section *préposition*.

Comment: Whoops, j’aurais dû proposer [cette question-ci](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9789/de-vs-des-in-plural-context), mais elle est en anglais… Je m’étonne de ne pas trouver de question en français à ce sujet, je suis sûr d’avoir déjà lu (ou écrit) quelque chose à ce sujet. Ça m’apprendra à mal lire les questions, tiens.

Comment: @Édouard: en fait le titre de la question était trompeur, et elle était bien similaire. Il y a beaucoup de questions qui tournent autour du même sujet.

Comment: je croyais qu'on disait "j'ai besoin de clients" et "j'ai besoin de vacances"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Les deux phrases seraient justes mais le sens est différent :

> J'ai besoin de lunettes

signifie que tu as besoin d'acheter des lunettes (techniquement "de des lunettes"), sans plus de détails.

> J'ai besoin des lunettes

signifie que tu as besoin de lunettes particulières (techniquement "de les lunettes"). Par exemple, des lunettes de protection, mais c'est au contexte de le préciser.

Note que la différence est exactement la même avec "clients". Par exemple :

> J'ai besoin de clients pour que ma société prospère.

Comment: Ok! Donc pourquoi on n'écrit pas "de des lunettes"? Parce que si j'ai compris correctement, l'expression "j'ai besoin" est suivi directement par "de", n'importe quoi. Par contre, en "j'ai besoin des lunettes", "des" est comme une contraction de "de+les". Est-ce que c'est ça?

Comment: Oui. "de des lunettes" n'est pas correct : on l'abbrège en "de lunettes". Attention par contre, "de mes lunettes" est correct pour indiquer la possession !

Comment: [Cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/14335/7361) semble similaire à la tienne.

Comment: @Chiara "j'ai besoin des lunettes" voudrait plutôt dire "j'ai besoin de ces lunettes", le contexte jouant dans le cas du "les" un rôle démonstratif indiquant desquelles il s'agit.